# entity framework, data annotations on multiple foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I have EF6 database first with multiple foreign keys from one table to another in the database. I am trying to use data annotations to change the name of each string from the primary table in partial classes i.e in the model.

```
public virtual Options_General_Advert Options_General_Advert_CentralLocation
 { get; set; }
public virtual Options_General_Advert Options_General_Advert_Garage 
 { get; set; }
public virtual Options_General_Advert Options_General_Advert_LivingRoom 
 { get; set; }
```

in the view they are appearing as

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Options_General_Advert_CentralLocation.option_description)
```

Can the display name be set for the virtual property using data annotations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. The only cure for bad data normalization is normalization.

Comment: Thanks Gert, So I am looking at a new table for each relationship